# about the sufficient conditions for complex differentiability via Cauchy-Riemann:

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity, cauchy-riemann-equations

I just noticed in the rule about the sufficient conditions for complex differentiability via Cauchy-Riemann:

When we're considering as to whether or not $g: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is differentiable at $z=z_0$, we don't need $g_x,g_y$ to be continuous on the entire neighbourhood of the point $z_0$. Apparently, all we need is that $g_x,g_y$ exist on the neighbourhood and are continuous merely at $z=z_0$ (and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann at $z=z_0$).

1. Is this correct?
2. Please give any example (preferably as simple as possible) where for $g: G \to \mathbb C$ ($G$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$), for $z_0 \in G$ and for open neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$ with $U \subseteq G$, we have that $g_x$ and $g_y$ exist but are **not continuous on the entire** $U \ \setminus \ \{z_0\}$ but are still continuous at $z_0$ and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann at $z=z_0$. There are probably some simple (yet difficult) examples that are obvious that I've missed, but please tell me anyway.

Comment: If you need to prove $P$, and if $P \iff Q$, then you can just prove $Q$. You don't have to use $P$ every damn time you have to prove $Q$.

Comment: @LeeMosher did you mean to say that if i don't have to use $P$ every damn time i have to prove a proposition $R$ which is implied by either $P$ or $Q$ ?

Comment: Yes, that also.